# Chrome Devtools Workspaces Autosave Javascript and HTML

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I know about this tool https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave

However, I would like to set up the workspaces manually in Chrome. If I apply new styles on the *Styles* panel they will be persisted automatically.

But when I enter new HTML or javascript, i have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in order to see the changes. I can't turn on autosave. Perhaps there is a setting in the settings panel, or a simple extension which will do this?

[image: Not saved]

Answer (score 0):

This is the [feature](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=544481) request you are looking for. Unfortunately they don't seem to be in any hurry so I advice to star it by as many people as possible.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>S</kbd>     for saving all files